# how to specify ; as field delimiter in spark in csv file reading

Tags: apache-spark

how to specify ; as field delimiter in spark

I have below code

DataSet dataset = session.format("csv").option.("delimiter ",);
please let me know what i can pass here in value

Comment: It is `delimiter` (or `sep`) not `delimater`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code to load data from a file delimited with ";". It can be changed to any other value.

**Input:**

```
San;1;100
Ku;3;200
Nam;3;200
```

**Spark Code:**

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter",";").load("test.dat")
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

**Output:**

```
root
|-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c2: string (nullable = true)

+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|
+---+---+---+
|San|  1|100|
| Ku|  3|200|
|Nam|  3|200|
+---+---+---+
```